# What exactly is the well defined phase of the BCS ground state wavefunction in superconductivity?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, wavefunction, superconductivity

After studying the BCS theory of superconductivity, I do not understand this quote from my notes:

> "The phase of the BCS wavefunction is well defined."

I do not see this "phase" from the coherent state  form of the BCS ground state. What is it?

Comment: You might find this article by Anderson helpful: http://journals.aps.org/rmp/abstract/10.1103/RevModPhys.38.298

Comment: Simply put, the phase is the $\phi$ in the expression for the wavefunction given here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/339747/what-is-the-link-between-the-bcs-ground-state-and-superconductivity?rq=1

Comment: This question is related to these ones : https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/284314/16689 and https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/310519/16689

Answer (score 2):

It just means that in the BCS ground state, all the electrons form bosonic pair states that condense in a single wavefunction, which hase a phase $\Phi_0$. In this case you can say that all the electrons "share" the same phase $\Phi_0$.

This is not the case in a general metallic state where electrons are much less correlated : their relative phases are random. In this case you say that the "global phase" is not well-defined.