# Superconducting order parameter seems to depend on the choice of the ground state wave function!

Tags: superconductivity, phase-transition

As it is described in [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/284314/bcs-state-with-well-defined-particle-number-interpretation) the BCS wave function has definite phase but indefinite electron number. Therefore the superconducting order parameter $\langle \phi| c_{k \uparrow}c_{-k \downarrow} |\phi\rangle$ can be nonzero. However one can construct a wave function with definite  particle number. In that case the order parameter $\langle N|c_{k \uparrow}c_{-k \downarrow} |N\rangle$ will be zero!

Why does the order parameter depend on our choice of the wave function?

Comment: The value of order parameters always depend on the choice of the wavefunction. Why would you think this is an issue?

Comment: Compared to e.g ferromagnet I assume the order parameter should have a definite value!

Comment: For the Ising ferromagnet you can also write states with zero magnetization.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch Yes but for $T<T_c$  magnetization (order parameter) must be nonzero, right?

Comment: No, there can are *always* (well, almost) states with zero order parameter, take e.g. |all up>+|all down>.  The point is that (i) random states have a non-zero order parameter, and more importantly (ii) there is long-range order (long-range correlations), which are independent of the ground state chosen, and which are closely linked to the maximum value of the order parameter.