# What is superconducting coherence length?

Tags: terminology, superconductivity, coherence, length

I'm an electronics student, and don't know much about some physics concepts.
I was studying superconductivity and came to the London equation, Meissner effect and BCS theory.
I kind of understood these things, but am still wondering: what is [superconducting coherence length](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superconducting_coherence_length)?
All I understood is it's related to the Fermi length and for type I semiconductor.

Answer (score 11):

Superconductivity is about the appearance of an energy gap $\Delta$ in the excitation spectrum of the electron quasi-particles, which become paired in the form of a Cooper pair below the critical temperature $T_{c}$.

An other important energy scale in metals (superconducting or not) is the Fermi energy $E_{F}$, which represents the baseline energy of all conduction electrons. So one can generate many interesting criteria by manipulating the energy gap and the Fermi energy. For instance $\Delta/E_{F}$ represents the strength of the superconducting binding of electrons in the form of Cooper pairs.

From these energies : the energy gap $\Delta$ and the Fermi energy $E_{F}=mv_{F}^{2}/2$ with $v_{F}$ the Fermi velocity and $m$ the conduction band mass, one can generate a natural characteristic length $\ell_{b.}\sim\frac{\hbar v_{F}}{\Delta}$. This characteristic length naively represents the size of the Cooper pair, and it is called the coherence length.

This was for clean system. In diffusive systems, there is in addition the diffusion constant $D$ which represents an area explored by unit of time. So the natural length scale constructed from $\Delta$ is $\ell_{d.}\sim\sqrt{\frac{\hbar D}{\Delta}}$. Since one usually takes $D\sim v_{F}\cdot l$, with $l$ the mean-free path, this is still related to the Fermi velocity, though different exponent.

Coherence length depends on temperature (because $\Delta$ depends on temperature, as e.g. $\Delta\sim\sqrt{T-T_{c}}$ in the Ginzburg-Landau regime), and it's related to the phase rigidity of the superconducting condensate : one needs to tilt the superconducting phase over the size of the superconducting coherence length to get some current. Also, coherence length is related to the penetration length a superconductor exhibits in contact with a normal metal. Since $\Delta\rightarrow0$ as $T\rightarrow T_{c}$, the coherence length diverges at the critical temperature, a hallmark of a critical phenomena (i.e. a second order phase transition here).

Superconducting coherence length appears naturally in many circonstances, as e.g. the penetration of the superconducting properties over non-superconducting materials. For instance, the Josephson current $j$ behaves as $j\sim \ell_{b.}/x$ in ballistic systems and as $j\sim e^{-x/\ell_{d.}}$ in diffusive systems at distance $x$ from the superconducting interface.

Comment: So, in short, the characteristic length generated by transition of electrons from normal to superconducting state, is called the coherence length.??

Comment: Jay I think it is more as FraSchelle mentions above.  This characteristic length naively represents the size of the Cooper pair, and it is called the coherence length. & one can generate a natural characteristic length ℓ∼ℏvF/Δ, with vF the Fermi velocity.

Comment: I forget to mention : $v_F$ is the only characteristic velocity of a normal metal, so it's natural to see it appearing in the construction of the characteristic length, and $\hbar$ mention its quantum origin. Otherwise, feel, free to construct a natural length-over-time constant in normal metal, like the atomic length scale over ... well, what ?

Comment: @JayyM Yes of course ! That's the way physicists think about a new system : what is the length the new property/ies can be shared over ? Surely the coherence length come from microscopic calculations as well (as e.g. transport equation in superconductors), but it's quite cumbersome to extract it from your question. So feel free to ask for more microscopic details in an other question. Note nevertheless that the superconducting coherence length is related to mesoscopic coherence length, as I discuss in [an other post here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/310519/16689).

Comment: @FraSchelle It is the characteristic component of the variations of the density of superconducting component. In the case of BCS theory, it is related to characteristic Cooper pair size.... Is this understood right by  me?

Comment: *It is the characteristic component of the variations of the density of superconducting component* : not exactly. In fact in bulk superconductor without external constraint there is no variation of the density of  the Cooper pairs. But if you apply an external constraint, like an interruption of the superconductor, or a current or a magnetic field you will perturb the superconducting condensate over characteristic distances of the order of magnitude of the coherence length. Strictly speaking, the coherence length is the characteristic length of the Cooper pair correlations (...)

Comment: Something like $\left\langle c^{\dagger}\left(x\right)c^{\dagger}\left(x^{\prime}\right)\right\rangle \propto e^{-\left(x-x^{\prime}\right)/\ell}$, with $\ell$ the characteristic length, and $ c^{\dagger}\left(x\right)$ the creation operator of an electron at position $x$. The gap is defined as $\Delta\left(x\right)\propto\left\langle c^{\dagger}\left(x\right)c^{\dagger}\left(x\right)\right\rangle $ so they are not completely related. But perhaps all this is far beyond you need for a hand-waving explanation, so you might stick with your own words :-)

Comment: Otherwise, keep in mind that the coherence length is basically the size of a Cooper pair. When you consider systems with size far larger than the coherence length, you might not worry too much about it, but if you consider structures of the size of the coherence length, then you enter interesting regimes, the study of which is called mesoscopic physics, hence the link to the electronic coherence length.

Answer (score 4):

I would like to add a more intuitive description to FraSchelle's nice answer.  As you guessed correctly, the coherence length is the correlation length associated with the phase transition from a superconducting to the normal state.   As with any other phase transition, this length describes how far fluctuations of the order parameter propagate.  In a superfluid or superconductor(superfluid of cooper-pairs),  the order parameter is the superfluid density or condensed cooper-pair density.  Fluctuation of this density implies exciting particles out of the condensate.  In a superconductor, you can have excited thermal cooper-pairs or you can have broken cooper-pairs, while for a superfluid of bosons, fluctuations of the density just excites thermal particles.

With this in mind you can image that at the boundary of a superconductor,  there will be a higher density of unpaired electrons coming from the neighbouring materials. The region of significantly unpaired electrons will have a depth related to the coherence length.

Similarly, the cloud of unpaired electrons around an impurity will have a radius proportional to the coherence length and the region of unpaired electrons at the center of a vortex  will again be the size of the coherence length.

Comment: Sorry but it the coherence length is the region of unpaired electrons, higher coherence length means more unpaired electrons. Doesn’t this spoil superconductivity as it needs Cooper pairs?

Comment: Yes,  This is why at the transition from superconductivity to a normal metal, the coherence length diverges.  Also why if you increase the fermi velocity, it increases( more kinetic energy to over come in "binding" cooper pairs).

Comment: So for a good superconductor you want a small coherence length?

Comment: depends on what you mean by good. but yea, a superconductor with a higher energy gap (the energy need to break a cooper pair and excite an electron) will have a smaller coherence length.

Comment: Does higher energy gap mean more stable superconductor? Against external perturbations I mean. So in this sense small coherence length is good I guess?

Comment: Yes,  the energy gap is the energy needed to "break" a cooper pair,  if this is larger, it's harder to break a pair (which would increase scattering/dissipation).  The small coherence length is more a by product of the a cooper-pairs being tightly bound.  For example, you could also decrease the coherence length by adding disorder and decreasing the mean free path of an electron. But this doesn't necessarily change the energy needed to break a pair.  Basically there are many other factors that determine the strength of the superconductor, and the coherence length is only an indicator.

Answer (score 0):

"An independent characteristic length is called the coherence length. It is related to the Fermi velocity for the material and the energy gap associated with the condensation to the superconducting state. It has to do with the fact that the superconducting electron density cannot change quickly-there is a minimum length over which a given change can be made, lest it destroy the superconducting state. For example, a transition from the superconducting state to a normal state will have a transition layer of finite thickness which is related to the coherence length. Experimental studies of various superconductors have led to the following calculated values for these two types of characteristic lengths." Sourced from following [Characteristic Lengths in Superconductors](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Solids/chrlen.html) .

See table for various Coherence lengths of various materials in the linked article.

I have also added another great youtube video link that also explains Coherence length in greater detail. An interesting point is the way impurities added to a pure material can be inserted into a material to upset its electronic density and its superconducting waveform and cause the material to lose its superconducting properties. The more I research coherence length the more I understand it as the cooper electron pairing that takes place at superconducting temperatures and the resultant waveform that each substance gives rise to and the waveforms with wavelengths that stop the penetration of external magnetism.

[Part2 Penetration Depth and Coherence Length.avi](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=67dEqg3GQf8)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So, as you said 'a transition from the superconducting state to a normal state' .. Is this related to Meissner Effect somewhere.?? Or just the transition is directly related to Coherence length, depending on the Fermi velocity?

Comment: Yes it is related to the Meissner Effect. If the Cooper pairing is sufficient  as a result of T->Tc superconducting will result and  Δ  -> 0  then the Meisner Effect or blocking of magnetism  occurs. And this waveform is described by this coherence length. One could imagine the degree of order of the Cooper Pairs is maintained for a said distance of degrees of freedom.

Answer (score 0):

It may be worth stressing that a reduced coherence length makes the superconducting state more sensitive to local perturbations and hence more fragile. As stated by Shane above, "the coherence length is the correlation length associated with the phase transition from a superconducting to the normal state". The shorter it is, the stronger the impact of  an impurity on the superconducting state will be. A short coherence length means low fault tolerance. The issue haunts HTS such as YBCO and BSCCO, limiting their usability.
There's a nice [article](https://www.mdpi.com/2410-3896/5/4/77) by Guy Deutscher about this.

Answer (score -1):

It´s he maximum difference in length of the path traveled between the two laser beams, or in other terms: it is the extension in space in which the wave has a sinusoidal shape in such a way that its phase can be safely predicted.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is this related to Superconductivity?

Comment: That's coherence length of a light beam.