# Characteristic lengths in SNS Josephson Junction

Tags: condensed-matter, superconductivity, josephson-junction, mesoscopic-physics

An S-N-S Josephson junction is formed by two Superconducting (S) leads separated by a normal metal (N)  which acts like the weak link. While studying,  I often encounter the words **diffusive**, **long**, **short**,  **in clean limit** and **dirty limit**. I  see that they describe the different regimes of the SNS Junction.

I am trying to establish a global understanding of these regimes based on the characteristic lengths existing on an SNS junction. Namely,

L:  Length of the normal metal

$\textbf{$L_b$ $\sim$  $\frac{\hbar V_F}{\Delta}$} :$ Coherence length (based on the [answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/375231))

$\textbf{$L_\Phi$ $\sim$  $\sqrt{\frac{\hbar D}{\Delta}}$} $    : Coherence length in diffusive regime

$\textbf{$L_{th}$ $\sim$ $\sqrt{\frac{\hbar D}{ k_b T}}$} $    : Thermal length in diffusive regime ([2](https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0008146))

Also,

$\epsilon_c = \frac{\hbar D}{L^²}$  : Thouless energy

According to [this article](https://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.73.184515), the characteristic voltage, $\textbf{$V_c = R_N  I_c$}$, is governed by $\epsilon_{c}$ or the gap $\Delta$. (whichever is smaller)

In light of these informations;

- Would it be correct to construct a table such as below ?

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|} \hline
    &\textbf{Long}&\textbf{Short}\\  \hline
\textbf{Diffusive} \\ \textit{(dirty limit)}&L >> L_{\phi},
(\epsilon_c << \Delta) &L << L_{\phi}, (\epsilon_c >> \Delta)\\  
   \hline
\\ \textbf{Ballistic} \\ \textit{(clean limit)} &L >> L_{b}&L << L_{b}\\  \hline
 \hline
\end{array}$$

- I can't see where $L_{th}$ fits in this picture. When and how does it become an important length scale ?

Thanks